# How to get a specific record from a table as the last record?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

For example, I have a table in Oracle db where the values in a column are:

A
B
C
D

I would like to fetch the following output from the table(here, B,C,D are in alphabetical order and A is put to the last):

B
C
D
A

Note: They have a unique key with the column if that helps.

Comment: Why have you tagged your request with SQL Server?

Comment: because there are people who might only seek questions from sql server, but I guess this question can be answered by them as well.

Comment: Okay. Don't do that, though. Either ask a SQL question for a specific DBMS (Oracle 11g here), or ask for a solution in standard SQL (in that case say so in the request and tag no DBMS). This time the solution for Oracle and SQL Server (and standard SQL) is actually the same, but this is not always the case.

Comment: @MTO, that question you refer to is more complex, and its answer as well. This is a basic question with a simple answer - i.e. much easier to understand for beginners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a `case` expression in the `ORDER BY` to put A rows at the end:

```
order by case when columnname = 'A' then 1 else 0 end, columnname
```

Comment: works perfectly. :)